# emails are sent to spam folder despite having DKIM and SPF set?

Tags: gmail, yahoo, spam, spf, dkim

My emails are delivered to spam folder at gmail and yahoo mail.
PTR, DKIM (1024 bit), SPF are okay. I don't know whether DMARC and ADSP or Domain Key are needed to be configured or else?
In addition, I have checked Bulk Senders Guidelines "support.google.com/ ----> mail/answer/81126" but I think I am in compliance with it, except the **Format** section of the webpage. I wonder is my email header is ISO-8859-1 compliant as is requested by gmail or my messages are formatted according to RFC 5322 as it is required!?

However, I have checked my email by various tools including:

```
1- www.brandonchecketts.com/emailtest.php
2- mail-tester.com (my email score: 10/10)
3- toolbox.googleapps.com ----> /apps/messageheader/analyzeheader
```

and all of them are ok and I can't get it right why my emails are categorised as spam?

By the way, I am not a bulk sender, my ip is clean (not in any of blacklists) and I have just started to configure my new VPS host.

I am confused a bit as it is obvious, Please guide me.
Note: (I have changed email addresses and real IPs in the message header)

Here is the header:

```
Delivered-To: user@gmail.com
Received: by 10.194.95.197 with SMTP id dm5csp291965wjb;
Fri, 30 Jan 2015 06:02:17 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.180.206.147 with SMTP id lo19mr5212607wic.32.1422626536876;
Fri, 30 Jan 2015 06:02:16 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <user@myemail.com>
Received: from myemail.com (myemail.com. [97.195.90.210])
by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id s3si20803914wjx.75.2015.01.30.06.02.16
for <user@gmail.com>
(version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
Fri, 30 Jan 2015 06:02:16 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of user@myemail.com designates 97.195.90.210 as permitted sender) client-ip=97.195.90.210;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@myemail.com designates 97.195.90.210 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=user@myemail.com;
dkim=pass header.i=@myemail.com
Received: from webmail.myemail.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
by myemail.com (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 0D4A122FAEF
for <user@gmail.com>; Fri, 30 Jan 2015 15:02:14 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=myemail.com;
s=default; t=1422626535;
bh=mg3gRDZT3ck+E3FdH2X4LLdsZ/+WeZuit/DVefJiJWc=;
h=Date:From:To:Subject;
b=NhJPZML/OvA/2LJbvqKxnV7AO3TeGPdDqwBI+iOceZk2bz2flsCun3AqJ4RPY8pqM
is+dlQWTFCmQ2T2He7cKU/nC28FmPY4cqwJgt6oSIW0bIWkh81JdzBZXoIDiBGGlkx
mkrpvKQ4vdFh2R7iIRmUJMJtAGWr7MGoS/J7sdi0=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII;
format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Fri, 30 Jan 2015 17:32:14 +0330
From: user@myemail.com
To: user@gmail.com
Subject: Hello
Message-ID: <7582a20431ca444b255e5e835e6ee87d@myemail.com>
X-Sender: user@myemail.com
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.0.0
```

Regards

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've said that you've modified the header records, it's hard to determine a few things.  However, the sending mail server seems to be webmail.domain.com  ---  Are the DNS records set to point to mail.domain.com or webmail.domain.com or both?

Since you've done the rest of the configuration: just enter a dmarc DNS record, it might increase your server's reputation.  Speaking of reputation, if your email server only handles a few emails a day from a couple of users - then your reputation as a 'spammy' server can be greatly affected by a just a few unopened or manually spam marked messages.  Also, I believe there's a time lag between when you setup a mail server and when it's reputation gets out of the 'default to spam' folder.